# I cannot find the error in my SQL Code?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to list the number and name of each customer that either is represented by sales representative 65 or that currently has orders on file, or both, and I keep getting an error. I even checked the solution in the book, and my code looks the same. What is this error telling me? I attached the solution the book gives as well. [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HCGo.png)

```
    mysql> SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
    -> FROM CUSTOMER
    -> WHERE REP_NUM+'65'
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT C.CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
    -> FROM CUSTOMER C, ORDERS 0
    -> WHERE C.CUSTOMER_NUM=0.CUSTOMER_NUM;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_NUM=0.CUSTOMER_NUM' at line 6
```

Comment: In the future, *please* tell us *what the error says*.

Comment: It was under the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `zero` as alias name that is the reason for error. Numbers are not allowed to be aliased. I think you `o` instead of `zero`

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
     FROM CUSTOMER
     WHERE REP_NUM = '65'  -- also here `=` should be used instead of `+`
     UNION
     SELECT C.CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
     FROM CUSTOMER C, ORDERS o
     WHERE C.CUSTOMER_NUM=o.CUSTOMER_NUM;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because the solution provided really looked like a 0 and not an o

Answer (score 1):

Uses `EXISTS`:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where rep_num = 65 or
      exists (select 1 from orders o where c.customer_num = o.customer_num);
```

Your specific problem is that you have used a number as a table alias.  You should really be using a letter.

However, other things come to mind:

- `union` is a resource hog, because it incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  That is not necessary for this query.
- numbers, such as `65`, should not be enclosed in single quotes -- these should be used for strings and dates.
- you have a `+` where `=` is called for.

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax,it is ='65' not +'65'

```
 mysql> SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
-> FROM CUSTOMER
-> **WHERE REP_NUM+'65**'
-> UNION
-> SELECT C.CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
-> FROM CUSTOMER C, ORDERS 0
-> WHERE C.CUSTOMER_NUM=0.CUSTOMER_NUM;
```